# php re-index numeric keys in associative array with combined numeric and string keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
 [20_fill_1] => Array
    (
        [autoTuned] => Array
            (
                [0] => fill-0*6.35*6.6*legitPhraseWith*VMWshkqbhfA*fill_3.mp4
            )

        [fill] => Array
            (
                [0] => fill-0*6.35*6.6*subwordPhraseWith*VMWshkqbhfA*fill_4.mp4
            )

        [1] => fill-0*6.35*6.6*legitPhraseWith*VMWshkqbhfA*fill_3.mp4
        [ill] => Array
            (
                [oil] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => oil-0*6.8*7.05*similarSubwordPhraseWith*HZNbg-1bz1c*oil_4.mp4
                    )

            )

    )
```

The reason there is no [0] is because I just unset it. Now I want that [1] to become the new [0], and if there were more numeric keys, i'd want them to also change so the numeric keys are in order. However, I need to keep the string keys.

Edit:this was the array before I removed the zeroth element:

```
[20_fill_1] => Array
    (
        [0] => added#fill-0*6.35*6.6*subwordPhraseWith*VMWshkqbhfA*fill_4.mp4
        [autoTuned] => Array
            (
                [0] => fill-0*6.35*6.6*legitPhraseWith*VMWshkqbhfA*fill_3.mp4
            )

        [fill] => Array
            (
                [0] => fill-0*6.35*6.6*subwordPhraseWith*VMWshkqbhfA*fill_4.mp4
            )

        [1] => fill-0*6.35*6.6*legitPhraseWith*VMWshkqbhfA*fill_3.mp4
        [ill] => Array
            (
                [oil] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => oil-0*6.8*7.05*similarSubwordPhraseWith*HZNbg-1bz1c*oil_4.mp4
                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: Looks to me like you may want to back up and think of another approach to solving your problem. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? I'm sure you could hack together a way to do what you're asking but it would be an ugly way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: well i'm unsetting values in the first array dimension that contain a certain string

Comment: @I need help please be more specific as much as yon can and explain your reasoning better so other can help you better :)

Comment: Please present a larger/better representation of your input, and show your expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array isn't very large, you could build another array:

```
$output = [];

foreach ($original as $key => $item):
  if(is_string($key)) $output[$key] = $item;
  else $output[] = $item;
endforeach;
```

`$output` is what you want.

#### Update:

You could also unshift (insert) a dummy element at the start of the array, then shift (remove) it. This will re-key the numerical keys and leave the string keys alone:

```
array_unshift($original,'dummy');
array_shift($original);
```

thanks to @brennonbrimhall for the inspiration.

Comment: sadly its a huge multidimensional array :/

Comment: @Ineedhelp must the element order be maintained?  The re-keying is just for the top-level array right? (in other words you don't need to go into the multi-dimensions to re-key sub-arrays.

Comment: @Ineedhelp I updated my answer so that you won't need to create a second array in memory, since your input is a huge array.

Comment: That `array_unshift()` + `array_shift()` is crazy, but wowzer does it work!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than unset the `0th` element, consider using [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php).  It will automatically remove the `0th` element, reindex other numerical indices, and preserve non-numerical keys and values.

Comment: sometimes it isn't the first element I am removing tho